# Colorizing 16 bit Greyscale Mat produces only half of image

Tags: c++, objective-c, opencv, image-processing, colors

I have been provided with a 16-bit greyscale matrix (Mat type = CV_16UC1) that I would like to colorize using OpenCV and a custom colormap gradient stored in an integer array. The colormap contains 256 RGB colors and is of the below format:

```
const int colormap[] = {R0, G0, B0, R1, G1, B1, ..., R255, G255, B255};
```

The grey-scale matrix contains a single unsigned char (between 0 and 255) per pixel point which I use as an index to find the corresponding RGB color in the `colormap` array.

The new colorized Mat is initialized as all black, with the same dimensions as the greyscale Mat, with the exception that it is a 3 channel matrix.

```
cv::Mat colorizedMat = cv::Mat::zeros(matGreyScale.rows, matGreyScale.cols, CV_16UC3);
```

I then use the below code to loop over each pixel of the `colorizedMat` and update it with the RGB values obtained from the `colormap`:

```
for (int row = 0; row < colorizedMat.rows; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < colorizedMat.cols; col++) {
        int pixelVal = matGreyScale.at<uchar>(cv::Point(col,row));
        cv::Vec3b color(colormap[pixelVal*3+2],colormap[pixelVal*3+1],colormap[pixelVal*3]);
        colorizedMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(col,row)) = color;
    }
}
```

However, this has resulted in the `colorizedMat` only being filled approximately halfway leaving the other half completely black as shown below. The image also seems slightly stretched.

Original grey scale image: [image: OriginalGreyScale]  Colorized image: [image: Colorized]

If I change the bounds of the inner for loop to `col < colorizedMat.cols*2`, the full Mat is colored in, however, the image is very stretched.

How would I correctly colorize a greyscale Mat using a custom colormap? Any help is greatly appreciated!

The images are tiny because the camera I'm receiving them from has has an 80x60 resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues I see.

1. Your `matGreyScale` was declared as CV_16UC1. However, you tried to access its elements with `matGreyScale.at<uchar>(cv::Point(col,row));`. This is incorrect because CV_16UC1 should be accessed using `matGreyScale.at<unsigned short>(...)`. It's confusing because `CV_16UC1` sounds like "unsigned char" but it's really "16-bit, unsigned, channels = 1)". See: http://dovgalecs.com/blog/opencv-matrix-types/
2. If you declare `colorizedMat` as `CV_16UC3`you should create vectors of type `Vec3s` for populating this matrix. Alternatively, you can do as Q.H. suggested above and declare `colorizedMat` as `CV_8UC3` and stick with creating vectors of type `Vec3b` (which makes more sense as your colormapped data is scaled 0-255). See:
   http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec

Comment: Thanks for the tips and links. I declared the vectors using Vec3s and populated the matrix that way and received the full width matrix back

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declared `colorizedMat` with incorrect depth:

```
cv::Mat colorizedMat = cv::Mat::zeros(matGreyScale.rows, matGreyScale.cols, CV_16UC3);
```

It should be `CV_8UC3` instead of `CV_16UC3`. Since `Vec3b` is the same with `Vec<uchar, 3>`, you only update half of `colorizedMat.data` with the command

```
colorizedMat.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(col,row)) = color;
```

Also, to be safe, declare color map as `uchar` (or `unsigned char`) type:

```
const uchar colormap[] = {R0, G0, B0, R1, G1, B1, ..., R255, G255, B255};
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with OpenCV. But I think It's wrong order when your call [Point()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d4e/classcv_1_1Point__.html)

```
Point_ (_Tp _x, _Tp _y)    
Template class for 2D points specified by its coordinates x and y.
```

Change your code like :

```
Point(row,col)
```

Might helps, might not.

Comment: The `x` coordinate would be the column number and the `y` coordinate would be the row, so the oder of the arguments in the OP's code is correct. Also, if these two were swapped, the image would be transposed, not simply cut in half.